# SQL injection dummy site error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to use SQL injection on a dummy site I have made to check that I can hack in to it but it seems as though the site is secure despite me not sanitising it. When I run the query I would use to do the injection on phpMyAdmin everything seems fine and the query runs, so I am wondering why it won't work when I input the data in a simple form which uses the post method.

```
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
   echo "login success";
}else {
   echo "login fail";
}
```

So can someone explain to me why this data is not prone to SQL injection? The line I am using to hack in to the site is the following

```
' or ' 1=1
```

And I add that into both the input fields

Comment: Where does `$username` come from? is it a post parameter?

Comment: ^ this. if $myusername is sanitized before that actual sql statement, then you're good. If it's not, then your site is anything but secure.

Comment: You did not show how you do the sql injection, how can we help?

Comment: apologies for the incomplete question I will edit it now to show more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not secure:

```
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 

$myusername = " ' or 1=1 LIMIT 1; -- "; // this will allow me to log in
```

Comment: Yes that is the point, but it does not seem to allow me to log in

Comment: did you add the dashes at the end?

Comment: Yes I did I have tried the following none seem to allow me to log in: ' or ' 1=1, ' or '1'='1 and ' or 1=1 --

Comment: No, that will not work, unless there's only one row in the table. Otherwise, all rows will be selected, hence `$count > 1`.

Comment: @kba Currently I have 3 rows in the table so 3 separate usernames and passwords, it still does not give me the desired result

Comment: Then something else is going wrong. The above will work. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af54c/1.

Comment: It was because of not using correct spacing in the login thank you